# Does this criss-crossed GND plane look like it will function properly?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, signal, ground-plane

I'll be using it at 12 MHz and...  not the best parts placement resulted in this board layout. So I am asking more experienced people if it will definitely not work or maybe it will. Thanks!

**edit** 
I was referring to the current return paths and their loops caused by the GND plane gaps, not more complicated things than that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the schematic as well? You can't expect us to reverse engineer a PCB.

Comment: I don't know about the ground plane stitching, but I see a lot of criss-crossing that makes me wonder if the layout could be improved.  Like, for example, move C9 down beside R21.  Then the connection from L1 to U5 doesn't have to flip sides.  Two less vias, and one less gap in your ground plane.

Comment: What I do is slap all the parts on the board, then push and rotate them so as to clean up the "rat's nest."  Fewer crossovers in the rat's nest means fewer crossed traces and much easier routing.

Comment: What is the ground current spectrum and where is it supposed to be 0V?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I...don't know

Comment: Then show the schematic to illustrate your question better

Comment: Is this a two-layer board? Because it looks like you have no problem routing traces between header pins, yet you open up the GND fill so that every header creates a GND slot. At 12 MHz, I think it will work fine, but if you can route a trace through pads on the top, then you can close the GND fill around the pins on the bottom, too. If those are 0.1" (2.54mm) spacing pins, there is no reason why you could not be able to close GND around them. Maybe make the pads a tiny bit smaller if you are concerned.

Comment: Like the others have said, I bet you can improve it if you spend some time moving stuff around. One other idea to keep in mind, you can use a zero ohm resistor as a jumper to avoid putting traces on GND. I would not worry that the board "won't work" but there is some possibility of signal integrity issues or unwanted RF emissions, or if you have any low-level analog stuff, maybe you could have unwanted coupling of digital signals into the sensitive stuff. If it is all digital and the fastest clock is 12 MHz, it will likely work fine.

Answer (score 1):

> So I am asking more experienced people if it will definitely not work or maybe it will. Thanks!

This must work by meeting CE safety, Emissions and ESD requirements to function as a Ground Plane.

You should have been given guidelines for ground plane requirements, such as air gap creepage clearances and avoiding sharp edges near grid connected conductors and line filter requirements.

> Will it radiate 12MHz?

<  Who knows where this energy gets radiated?

> Will it pass EMC & Safety requirements?

< unlikely
< not quite meeting creepage and sharp corners near high voltage ( which reduce E-field breakdown voltage significantly).
[image]

Sharp corners are known to reduce insulation voltage ( or BDV) down to 1/2 to 1/3 of smooth flat surfaces, which are further degraded by surface dust and humidity according to contamination tables in  IEC 60950-1.

< no evidence of a filter or a rise time or current-limit to the MOV clamp. ( which has limited surge cycles before it expires that may not blow fuse )

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have edited the schematic in. Which switching regulator ? `IC1` is linear while the one inside the 5.1V adapter is already filtered. As for the creepage voltage AFAIK it is 1.5mm for 220V. I have kept the power line traces at no less than around 3 mm. Not really sure which those sharp corners are. So please explain a little. Also, I see someone has downvoted the answer. I wonder if he had a good reason for that.

Comment: There are always some biased silent critics on this site.

Comment: I don't know which pollution conditions you have of the IEC 60950-1 spec, but I recall 1.5mm air gap is ok but FR4 surface may needs to be 2.5 to 3mm for 230Vac but when new may pass HiPot .

Comment: Often it's the Moderators who are the worst silent critics.

Comment: Some people seem to have trolls following them and down-voting every answer they make.

Comment: I see it as a failure to moderate constructively

Comment: Some more editing on `a filter or a rise time or current-limit to the MOV clamp` will be appreciated. Maybe link me to some practical examples.